# trouble uploading .pdf files and .doc to reserve

Tags: php, html

this is how I should have upload pdf files and. doc to the server and the website.

The problem is such that it just appears in the database and write "array", and I have written var_dump to find it fail and it says:

```
array(5) { ["name"]=> string(15) "hello.docx" ["type"]=> string(71) "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpX85fgs" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(2421) }
```

it is such that I must have it in **opgaveFile**

PHP

```
move_uploaded_file("/opgaveFile/" . $_FILES["file"]);
    var_dump($_FILES["file"]);
    /*
    if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO dwopgaver (title, filenavn) VALUES (?, ?)')) { 
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $title, $filenavn);
        $title = $_POST["title"]; 
        $filenavn = $_FILES["file"];
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->close();

    } else {
        echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklæringen: ' . $this->mysqli->error;
    }
    */
```

Html

```
<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                <table width="90%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Title</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="title" maxlength="50"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Filer</td>
                        <td><input type="file" name="file"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" name="opret" value="Upload Opgave" class="click border"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
```

Comment: PDF less so, but it's dying. DOC is just horrid.

Comment: You should probably read the documentation on move_uploaded_file or at the very least find a tutorial for uploads. `$_FILES['file']` is an array, you can't just append that to a folder and expect the file to magically appear.

Comment: @bjb568 what you mean on its?

Comment: @JonathanKuhn How will you do that, you have a video or link to how I might just do that?

Comment: It's? It is? What? Oh, and why did my comment get deleted?

Comment: @bjb568 i have not deletede you comment

Comment: Well, the documentation is available at http://www.php.net/move_uploaded_file with examples and all. You can probably search for a video if you need one. I hear youtube is good.

Comment: @user3187390 I know, you couldn't have. Weird... maybe a moderator got confused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from `var_dump`, `$_FILES["file"]` is an array. You need to extract the specific elements of it to get the appropriate attributes.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/opgaveFile/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
var_dump($_FILES["file"]);

if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO dwopgaver (title, filenavn) VALUES (?, ?)')) { 
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $title, $filenavn);
    $title = $_POST["title"]; 
    $filenavn = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->close();

} else {
    echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklæringen: ' . $this->mysqli->error;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand that comment.

Comment: i need to make its here: `opgaveFile/`

Comment: Then take the `/` off the beginning of the argument to `move_uploaded_files`. What's the problem?

Comment: i have compelete its now :) and its work for me now :D